# Giving more than the required notice

Tags: contracts, notice-period

I have one months notice period stated in my contract.

If I handed my notice in with a 3 month notice, would they be able to refuse and hold me to a one month notice period?

Comment: Why do you want to hand in your notice earlier than the obliged one month?

Comment: One month or "a minimum of one month"?

Comment: The answer depends entirely on the terms of your contract, and that's really more of a legal question.

Comment: If you want/need to keep the job for the next 3 months, do not give notice until one month.  There is no telling what the employer might do once they know you are leaving.  Perhaps they foresee the next 3 months as slow and let you go immediately to save the $.

Comment: There is alot of information missing here to give you a definitive answer.  What country are you in? Are you an employee or a contractor?  Why are telling them you leaving(Miltary DEP is protected)?  For that reason I have voted to close until the context is filled in.

Comment: @RyanMurphy Answers might be more useful if you gave us a clue why you would want to give such extensive notice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DISCLAIMER: I'm not a lawyer, and the correct answer depends on both the exact terms of your contract, and the laws of the country you live in.

In general, I think that your employer could choose to terminate your contract immediately, taken into account the notice period of one month. Therefore, handing in your notice three months in advance is a risk.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is not necessarily any different than most situations for most at-will employees, at least in the USA. Though you're going to run into a complicated situation of "are you being fired?" types of things too and things may get more complicated.